# Specific implementation of SlidingRDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, sliding-window

I am facing a very interesting problem, that can be formulated as follows :

Given a RDD of String, compute a RDD of pairs of consecutive rows. As for an example, if the input is a RDD with values "b","c","f","d","a", then the expected output is ("a","b"),("b","c"),("c","d"),("d","f")

We can easily do it by applying the following code:

```
val sorted = input.sortByKey()
val output = RDDFunctions.fromRDD(sorted).sliding(2)
```

But the use of [slidingRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/rdd/SlidingRDD.html) is really time-consuming, so I was asking myself if there is a better way to solve this problem.

Edit : 
Using the following code on my computer

```
test("sliding"){
        val rdd = sqlContext.read
          .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
          .option("header", "true")
          .option("inferSchema", "true")
          .option("mode", "FAILFAST")
          .option("delimiter", ";")
          .load(s"${testDataPath}filter/firstLastRand10x6.csv").select("first").sort("first").rdd

    val slidingRdd = RDDFunctions.fromRDD(rdd).sliding(2).collect()
  }
```

takes a reasonable time (around 18 sec) while when caching the rdd, it takes a huge time (around 150 sec) ! That seems very strange to me since we should avoid doing twice the lineage when caching. Does anyone have an explanation ?

I put the input file at this [url](http://www.sendbox.fr/ad658f148fea4a1a/firstLastRand10x6.csv)

Comment: `sliding` requires two jobs but in general shouldn't cost much more than 2 * `map(identity)`.  `sortByKey` from the other hand is expensive.

Comment: @zero323 : sliding is really expensive in my example, it take two jobs as you say. But when I look at the DAG, in the first job the lineage is reduceByKey->filter->map->sortByKey->reduceByKey, and the second job is sortByKey->flatmap->map->reduceByKey->flatMap->map->mapPartitions. Moreover, I don't see how to avoid my sortByKey so that the sliding is working properly.

Comment: So the problem is not `sliding` which doesn't require shuffles. It is the rest of your code. In other words expensive is the way how you create `input` RDD.